# Alfresco - Start Replication Job as User (from Dashlet)

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts, dashlet

I created a Dashlet in Alfresco Share with an Overwiew of the Replication Jobs. I changed the permissions in the Replication Definition Webscripts from admin to user. As Admin i can start the Replication Job from the Dashlet.

Is it possible to adjust the permissions, that a Site Manager or User can start the Replication Job? I still got a "Access Denied Problem". 
Where do i have to look at?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

No, all the Replication Job WebScripts explicitly require admin privileges so it is not possible to do this out-of-the-box.

If you *really* want to achieve this then your only option would be to override the relevant WebScripts (essentially copy/paste the defaults) and change the *.desc.xml files to change

```
<authentication>admin</authentication>
```

to be

```
<authentication>user</authentication>
```

However, that would make them available for *any* user to run. You would need to further edit the WebScripts to make checks that the user is a member of a specific group.

Comment: Thanks! I changed already the authentication in every WebScript and i still get an Access denied Error. The dashlet to start the replication job is only visible for Site Managers.

Comment: Changings the authentication in the WebScripts doesn't help. I also changed the permission for the replication definition itself, but i still get an access denied error. any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the authentication to

```
<authentication runas="admin">user</authentication>
```

That helped for me.